# Does role require AWS accesskey and password

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-iam

I have a role and I am trying to write a python script to access S3. It says boto3exception credentials not found. Do I need an AWS access key and password and keep in ~./aws/credentials to access S3?

Comment: Unless your S3 bucket is public for the type of access that you're requesting then, yes, you need credentials. If your code is trying to assume an IAM role then, yes, you need credentials for that. Do the credentials have to be `~./aws/credentials`? No, but they have to be provided to the Python script somehow and that file is one standard option for storing and retrieving AWS credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways in which you can supply credentials to boto3.

From the [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/credentials.html):

> The order in which Boto3 searches for credentials is:
>
> 1. Passing credentials as parameters in the boto.client() method
> 2. Passing credentials as parameters when creating a Session object
> 3. Environment variables
> 4. Shared credential file (~/.aws/credentials)
> 5. AWS config file
>    (~/.aws/config)
> 6. Assume Role provider
> 7. Boto2 config file (/etc/boto.cfg
>    and ~/.boto)
> 8. Instance metadata service on an Amazon EC2 instance that has an IAM role configured.

these are evaluated in order. Whichever one evaluates to credentials will be used.